# PDO: fetchAll assign array variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been fighting with this small line of code for about 2 hours now, researching with it and trying to figure out where I went wrong. After 9 hours of coding, I hit this little problem and now I'm in deep water. I have a 3800 line code at this point that relied on this and it's dead in the water.

The problem is that none of the final variables are coming back with any information, they're coming back entirely blank/null. When I try to assign "myname" with "$getranks['nickname']", it doesn't even do anything, even though my "print_r($getranks)" comes back with ALL of that information. I also tried fetch instead of fetchAll, but then I only get one result.

I took an old MYSQL website I made for a group on the internet which was subject to SQL Injection, so I remade it using PDO entirely. This is the problem I have.

Any help is much appreciated. I've got a headache and I'm going to go grab a late dinner while I wait for assistance. Thanks everyone.

**The Code: "index.php"**

```
$myid = $_SESSION['user'];

echo "User Session ID #" . $myid . ".<br><br>";

if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $checkrank = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE id = :myid");
    $checkrank->bindParam(':myid',$_SESSION['user']);
    $checkrank->execute();

    $getranks = $checkrank->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);

        print_r($getranks);
        $myname = $getranks['nickname'];
        $mycallsign = $getranks['callsign'];
        $mystatus = $getranks['status'];
        $mycallnum = $getranks['callnumber'];
        $myrank = $getranks['rank'];
        $mynote = $getranks['note'];
        $mybadge = $getranks['mybadge'];

    echo "<br><br>Check rank passed, the query came back with information.<br/>";
    echo "The session ID used to retrieve this information in the query was: " . $myid;
    echo "<br> Your name is " . $myname . ".";
}
```

**The Result:**

```
    User Session ID #0102.

Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 0102 [badge] => 201 [rank] => 6 [nickname] => Rodger Anderson [username] => MASKED [password] => MASKED [salt] => MASKED [email] => MASKED [note] => [callsign] => [profile] => http://www.MASKED.net/forums/member.php?MASKED [callnumber] => [status] => ) ) 

Check rank passed, the query came back with information.
The session ID used to retrieve this information in the query was: 0102
Your name is .

You are SESSION[0102]
Your name is [] and your badge number is #.
```

**The OLD Code:**

```
$myid = $_SESSION['user'];

    echo "User Session ID #" . $myid . ".<br><br>";

    if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logins WHERE id = $myid");
        $getranks = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

        $myname = $getranks['nickname'];
        $mycallsign = $getranks['callsign'];
        $mystatus = $getranks['status'];
        $mycallnum = $getranks['callnumber'];
        $myrank = $getranks['rank'];
        $mynote = $getranks['note'];
        $mybadge = $getranks['mybadge'];

        echo "<br><br>Check rank passed, the query came back with information.<br/>";
        echo "The session ID used to retrieve this information in the query was: " . $myid;
        echo "<br> Your name is " . $myname . ".";
    }
```

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: `$myname = $getranks['name'];` instead of nickname?

Comment: Sorry - None of the variables are coming back at all. "Your name is BLANK and your badge number is BLANK" but session['user'] is just fine. -- That was a type, fixing that now. I had to ommit some things when I copy and pasted.

Comment: `$getranks` is an array of `stdClass` objects so you'd at least need `$myname = $getranks[0]->nickname`. You're also not using `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` correctly. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#example-1070

Comment: Thanks @Phil - That got my name to show up, but the others are still blank. Moving forward at least. I was under the impression that FETCH_CLASS returned the column properties instead of the numerical value of the column. If I don't use anything it returns both, which is more memory than needs to be used.

Comment: You want `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` or `PDO::FETCH_OBJ` (see http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters). If you're only expecting one record, you probably shouldn't be using `fetchAll`. I suggest you read the documentation thoroughly.

Comment: I was wanting to grab all of the columns of the row that was located for the user account, so we can turn all of the results into single variables, so instead of calling "getranks['nickname']" through the whole webpage, I can just use "myname", that's why I used fetchAll

Comment: Solved. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @MichaelHarris that's not what `fetchAll` does; it  fetches all **rows**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$getranks` is an array of objects, not an associative array. Look at the results from your `print_r($getranks)`.

You should be doing something like

`$myname = $getranks[0]['nickname'];`

Or use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` but even then you'll need the [0].

Comment: $myname = $getranks[0]['nickname']
That just solved the entire issue. As I replaced each one with the correct column it worked just fine... So what's the difference between when I previously used "mysql_fetch_assoc" and PDO FetchAll? I'm trying to learn how to shift from MYSQL to PDO, which isn't working out too well as you can tell.

Comment: The difference is the same as the difference between `mysql_fetch_array` and `mysql_fetch_assoc`. A good exercise for you to go through would be to look at the MySQL function calls and then figure out the PDO counter part. Until you do that, you'll be plagued by this sort of small buggish type of things.